# Create an object at every nth Element of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array with an unknown Number of data that I want to normalize.
How can I push n elements and create object at nth Element of the initial Array in JavaScript?

Eg.: I get an Array with size=10000

```
["name: john", "dob:20/01/99","name: Christine", "dob:40/01/99", "name: Loub", "dob:30/01/99".......]
```

I want an achieve like this below

```
{"name": "john","dob:20/01/99"},{"name":"Christine","dob:40/01/99"}.........
```

What I have tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++){

    var entry = arry[i];

    if(i % 2){ 
        var x = {}
        x.push(entry)
    }
}
```

Comment: desired result is invalid syntax.

Comment: perhaps you mean `[{"name": "john","dob":"20/01/99"}, ...]` in your desired result?

Comment: Original data is an array of strings...

Comment: What output are you getting with your attempted code?

Comment: Your code currently fails because it's calling `push` on an object (`x`). If you want to add `x` to your array, you'll likely want to [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it in.

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis can you confirm what your desired output is supposed to be? The data looks like it is supposed to be JSON, but it is not quite in the right format. I just want to make sure you have formatted it correctly for this question.

Comment: @jwatts1980 yes I want the final result to be in json

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off with a structure like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "john",
        dob: "1/1/2020"
    },
    {
        name: "jane",
        dob: "1/3/2020"
    },
    etc.
]
```

```js
let arr = ["name: john", "dob:20/01/99","name: Christine", "dob:40/01/99", "name: Loub", "dob:30/01/99"]

let res = arr.reduce((acc,cur,idx,arrC) => {
    if(idx % 2 === 0){
        let name = cur.split(":")[1].trim()
        let dob = arrC[idx+1].split(":")[1].trim()
        acc.push({name: name, dob: dob})
    }
    return acc
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input seems to be an array of strings that respect the following form :

```
"<key>:<value>"
```

and sometimes with a space before the value. All you are missing is to do is split the string with that separator. Also you should have

```
if (i % 2 === 0)
```

because you want every pair index to be a new object. Also you need `entry[i + 1]` at every iteration. But you can also simply increment `i` by 2
Here's the fixed code :

```
var arry = ["name: john", "dob:20/01/99","name: Christine", "dob:40/01/99", "name: Loub", "dob:30/01/99"];

var objs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i += 2){
  var v1 = arry[i].split(':').map(s => s.trim());
  var v2 = arry[i + 1].split(':').map(s => s.trim());
  var obj = {};
  obj[v1[0]] = v1[1];
  obj[v2[0]] = v2[1];
  objs.push(obj);
}

console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create a new array with a length which is half of the original. In the iteratee function, slice two items, and map them to entries form ([[key, value], [key, value]]), and then convert the to an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const arr = ["name: john", "dob:20/01/99","name: Christine", "dob:40/01/99", "name: Loub", "dob:30/01/99"]

const result = Array.from({ length: arr.length / 2}, (_, i) => // create a new array with half the size of the original
  Object.fromEntries( // convert entries to an object
    arr.slice(i, i + 2) // take two items from the original array
    .map(str => str.split(/:\s*/)) // map them to [key, value] entries
  )
)

console.log(result)
```